# Reading qrcode (non-unique) once per session with Arkit+Vision

Tags: swift, qr-code, arkit, apple-vision

Given two `QRcode` (not unique) fixed in space.
As with `Arkit` and Vision, count each code once per session, even if we take away the camera.

I managed to write reading `QRcodes` into a session (hitTest) and using Vision to recognize and add a 3D object, but how to read two (or more) identical barcodes on the screen once (even if we remove the camera and return the `QRcodes` to the same)?
Can  remember them  coordinates?

Please tell me please

Comment: euh remember the result of the qr code? or a hash? and if it matches a previous than don't count em?

Comment: Tarick Welling, in the camera session, the qrcodes hash of the recognition results is different.

Comment: I guess that your hash is then a bad hash. What hash are you using?